# Adding and Fetching tuples values from Django model Column

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am new to Django/DRF
I am using DRF along with MySql for creating Rest APi
how can i achieve below mentioned points ?

Can anyone please help

I had two table

1. Booking - >> id, data, desc, services
2. Services - >> sid, service_name, type

There are two type of services Type1 and Type2

Note: there are fixed 10 services in both the Type which customer can choose while booking

i had two doubt.

1. Booking can have multiple service. so in services column i wanted to store array. [1,2,3] or comma separated services id.
2. Now when fetching records.i want get booking id details along with services name.
   for example
   {id,data, services: [{sid,service_name}}
   {id:1, data:"text", services: [{1,"text1"},{2,"text2"]}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write:

```
# models.py
class Service(models.Model):
    service_name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=(('type1', 'Type1'), ('type2', 'Type2'))

class Booking(models.Model):
    data = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    services = models.ManyToManyField(Service)

# serializers.py
class ServiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Service
        fields = ('id', 'service_name')

class CreateBookingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Booking
        fields = ('id', 'data', 'desc', 'services')

class ReadBookingSerializer(CreateBookingSerializer):
    services = ServiceSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
```